# More English nouns like "jeans", "glasses", "statistics", and "shorts", having no singular equivalent

Tags: nouns

Besides "jeans", "glasses", "statistics", and "shorts", what are some other plural nouns in English that end on "-s" and don't become their corresponding singular-noun counterparts by merely dropping "-s"?

Comment: *Statistic* is the singular of *statistics*. You would do better with *mathematics*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tongs, trouses.scissors are some of them I remember. you need to  consult  a good grammar   book to know the list.

Here is  a link which  may help you.

https://www.grammaring.com/nouns-which-are-always-plural

Comment: Isn't a scissor one of the two constituents of scissors?

Comment: No. we do not  say  scissor.

Comment: @JVL - except in those relatively rare cases we use it as a verb or as a modifier (as in _scissor kick_, e.g.)